# Span Text Hidden by Animated DIV Despite z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I'm working on a hobby project of mine -- it's something of a glorified RSS feed reader/grabber. I've been able to get most things working, but for some reason I cannot get the text in a certain span to be drawn above an animated div.

When a feed is grabbed, certain operations are performed before displaying the results. During this time, I keep track of the progress and display them in an animated "progress bar" div. All of the sub-operations each have their own progress bars, and they all work correctly (text on top of bar), but the final progress bar (overall progress) does not layer the text correctly.

I created a [simple mock-up in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfYfn/) to give an example of my problem.

```
$('#progress-total-box').bind('click', draw);

function draw() {
    if (($('#progress-totalbar-fill').css('width')) == "0px") {
        $('#progress-total-box').unbind();
        $('#progress-totalbar-fill').animate({width: '100%'}, 2000, function() {
            var description = document.createElement('span');
            $(description).attr('id', '#progress-total-text');
            $(description).html('100%');
            $('#progress-totalbar-empty').append(description);
            $('#progress-total-box').bind('click', draw);
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#progress-total-box').unbind();
        $('#progress-totalbar-fill').animate({width: 0}, 2000, function() {
            document.getElementById('progress-totalbar-empty').innerHTML = '';
            $('#progress-total-box').bind('click', draw);
        });
    }
}
```

The style/position/etc is purely for sake of demonstration. In this example, when the grey loading bar div is clicked, it animates its width from 0% to 100% (or vice-versa). When the animation is complete, a new child span is created and appended to the 'empty bar' background div, wherein the total percentage is displayed (100%, in this case).

This span element is intentionally removed when the bar is reset.

Do you guys have any ideas as to what's going wrong, and how I can fix it?

I have encountered this error is present in both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing you need to change is to remove the `#` from `$(description).attr('id', '#progress-total-text');`. You're assigning an ID to your span that begins with a `#`.

Comment: Ah, that was just a mistake in the JSFiddle. It's not in the real version. Nice catch, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

First off, you need to remove the `#` from this line

```
 $(description).attr('id', 'progress-total-text');
```

The new span, was never getting the css it was supposed.
Second, you need to either change your markup or your css. 
In this case, I updated the CSS, but the id name don't make sense anymore

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 0;
}

#progress-category-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

#progress-total-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    top: 32.5%;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #515A5C;
}

#progress-totalbar-empty {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #97b0b1;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 3;
}

#progress-totalbar-fill {
    position: relative;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -42px;
    border-left: 1px solid #97b0b1;
    border-top: 1px solid #97b0b1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #97b0b1;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    z-index: 2;
}

#progress-total-text {
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    top: 30%;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Thing is, you were showing the animated div over the text. 
So I put the text over the animation and put a transparent background behind it.
I applied the grey background to the container instead. I also changed it's height and applied `height:100%` to it's children.

[Here's a full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfYfn/1/)

Comment: Nice catch about the # in the attr line, that was just an error on my part when writing the mock-up. You caught the real error, though -- the incorrect layering -- but I'm not really sure why it worked for all of the other progress bars (which are configured in an identical manner). At any rate, thanks for your help! You've spared me an enormous headache.

Comment: @SamuelMS You're welcome my good sir. In case you're not already using it, I suggest you install an element inspector such as Firebug for firefox (Safari, Chrome, IE already has on). Right click on the element and you can access the properties directly. That's how I noticed that the text was underneath the animated layer. Cheers!